# c - How do I redirect command-line arguments to a function?

Tags: c, command-line, command-line-arguments, cs50

I'm taking the CS50 course, and in the following function, I wrote a set of code to check if a user-inputted command-line argument is valid or not. I decided to relegate this to a function, as it took up a large portion of my main code.

However, I'm unsure how to actually assign command-line arguments to a function. Here is the code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int valid(int a,string mystring);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    valid(argc, argv[]);
}

int valid(int a, string mystring)
{
    if (a == 2)
    {
        int j = 0;
        int n = strlen(mystring[1]);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (isalpha(mystring[1][i]) == false)
            j++;
        }
        if (j == 0)
        {
            if (n == 26)
            {
                printf("Success.\n");
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Key must contain 26 characters.\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I receive the following error message(s) when I try to compile it.

```
substitution.c:10:22: error: expected expression
    valid(argc, argv[]);
                     ^
substitution.c:18:24: error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'const char *'; take the address with & [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]
        int n = strlen(mystring[1]);
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~
                       &
/usr/include/string.h:384:35: note: passing argument to parameter '__s' here
extern size_t strlen (const char *__s)
                                  ^
substitution.c:21:36: error: subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector
            if (isalpha(mystring[1][i]) == false)
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~^~
/usr/include/ctype.h:190:32: note: expanded from macro 'isalpha'
# define isalpha(c)     __isctype((c), _ISalpha)
                                   ^
/usr/include/ctype.h:89:31: note: expanded from macro '__isctype'
  ((*__ctype_b_loc ())[(int) (c)] & (unsigned short int) type)
```

What changes can I make so my `valid` function will take command-line arguments?

Comment: The function arguments should be identical those in `main`, i.e. `int valid(int argc, string argv[])` Then call the function like this: `valid(argc, argv)`

Comment: @user3386109 yep that fixed it. I tried that before and it gave me an error, so I must have misstyped it while defining it. Thank you so much!

Comment: `strlen` takes string as argument but you are passing single character to it, One other thing, You want to create this in `C` style or `C++`? cause you are using `C++` string but you didn't even include strings.

Comment: @AriaN this isn't C++ string. It's a typedef for char[] from cs50.h. And if you ask me it only serves to confuse students.

Comment: @IvanC Confusing to me too, Thanks for informing.

Comment: Sorry, what is `string` type?  There's no `string` type in C, so you must have defined it somewhere.  Where is it defined and how?

Answer (score 0):

Your error comes in because your function accepts a string as a parameter. However, `string argv[]` is not a string. Instead, it is an array of strings. Hence, the error message is essentially telling you that you must pass `strlen` a string. However, since your function accepts a string as a parameter, `mystring[1]` evaluates to a `char`.

To fix this, you'd need to change your function definition to accept an array of strings, rather than simply just one string.